# Create instance from string by reinterpret cast

Tags: c++, c++11

My C++ is a bit rusty, for refreshing I am attempting to write a fcgi handler. I want to provide a class to hold the header fields. Since the header comes as a `char[]` from the socket and is 64 bits, I would like to have a constructor that simply copies the first 8 bytes into the instance data and is done. While I have some ideas how to this element wise I am afraid this might result in more than one copy operation on a 64 bit machine. I also would like to employ the initialiser list to prevent default construction overhead (which might not exist for chars). Since I find it hard to describe it in words here is the problem in C++, at first the class basic layout:

```
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>

class header {
    const boost::uint8_t version;
    const boost::uint8_t type;

    const union {
        boost::uint16_t requestId;
        struct {
            boost::uint8_t requestIdB1;
            boost::uint8_t requestIdB0;
        };
    };

    const union {
        boost::uint16_t contentLength;
        struct {
            boost::uint8_t contentLengthB1;
            boost::uint8_t contentLengthB0;
        };
    };
    const boost::uint8_t paddingLength;
    const boost::uint8_t reserved;

    header(char* header);
    ~header();

    //utility methods/getter
};
```

Now the constructor has to be written. I could write something like:

```
header::header(char* header) : version(header[0]), type(header[1]) , ..., reserver(header[7]) {}
```

however I am afraid that this will involve mulitple byte copies rather than one 8-Byte Word copy. Is there a better way to write this? I would still like to be able to write `header theHeader(&socketBuffer)` rather than `header theHeader=&reinterpret_cast<header*>(&socketBuffer)` [socketBuffer is a char[]].

Considering C++11 also the following might work, however I am wondering if there is a better way.

C++11 forwarding to default copy constructor after cast:

```
header::header(char* header) : header(*reinterpret_cast<header*>(&socketBuffer)) {}
```

Comment: Why do you believe "this will involve multiple byte copies"? Did you verify this?

Comment: @KerrekSB I did not verify that, I am just "afraid", and I would like to know what the best technique is for this (I assume) common case is.

Comment: Why don't you use `memcpy`? It is intended to copy memory blocks in most effective way possible.

Comment: @KirillGamazkov: Did you mean "efficient"? There's a limit to how effective a copy can be: Either you made a copy, or you didn't.

Comment: @KirillGamazkov RAII is one reason, meaning the data is written twice (first the default constructors run, then I can call memcpy from the constructor), besides that `memcpy(static_cast<void*>(this), static_cast<void*>(headerCharArrayPtr), sizeof(header))` involves a function call unless the compiler optimizes that and memcopies looping away. If `memcpy` would be the awnser I would brefer the manual Initialization list as long as it is short.

Comment: @KerrekSB, yes, I meant "efficient"